# Is there any way to close a file stream when I don't know where it has been opened?

Tags: java, file, stream

I'm working with a framework that process a folder, does some operations and returns me a file.

After that I want to delete the folder and all files in it, but the framework is leaving an open fileinputstream somewhere and I can't delete it.

I've been searching for a way to close the stream, but all the answers say that there is no way to close the stream, the answers are quite old so that's why I'm asking again, if there is someone who knows of a new way or any method to do this because I have no access to the framework and I really need to delete this folder.

Comment: Which File Stream to be specific are you talking about ?

Comment: Only way is to fix the framework so it doesn't leak resources. Talk to the framework creators, or fix it yourself if it is open-source.

Comment: Fix framework or change file system!! for example in Linux(like Ext4) you can delete file while another process reading it but in windows you can't! The second approach is not recommended!

Comment: Edited to specify stream type(fileinputstream), accessing the framework is my last option because it will take me a lot of hours to find where it is leaving the stream open, but if there is no other option I will need to do that.

Comment: Though I agree with other comments to fix the framework. But just out of curiosity, can you share the code snippet where you are deleting the folder. I have something in mind. Let's see whether it would work or not. I will definitely try though.

Comment: it is a simple function that deletes all files using File.delete(), it is working perfectly with all functions of the framework but an specified one.

Comment: @Andreas I suggest making an Answer of your Comment, so we can mark this Question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way is to fix the framework so it doesn't leak resources.

Talk to the framework creators, or fix it yourself if it is open-source.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any way to close a file stream when I don't know where it has been opened?*

No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the framework from a different process and remove the file after that process has terminated. The OS will close any remaining open files during cleanup.

Comment: I thought about that, I think that will be the best option on this case.